# Invalid initialization of reference type in subscript overloading function using class template

Tags: c++, class, templates, arraylist, operator-overloading

I am having a problem with overloading the subscript operator in a class template. I have the following header file to declare the class template (I only include the relevant function):

arrayListType.h

```
template <class elemType>
class arrayListType {
public:
    arrayListType<elemType>& operator[](int);
    arrayListType(int size = 100);
    virtual ~arrayListType();
protected:
    elemType *list;    // array to hold the list elements
    int length;        // variable to store the length of the list
    int maxSize;       // variable to store the maximum size of the list
};

template <class elemType>
arrayListType<elemType>& arrayListType<elemType>::operator[](int index) {
    assert(0 <= index && index < length);
    return list[index];
}
```

And I have the following code in main.cpp, where felinoTipo is a different derived class with its own attributes and works fine. Also, I did not show function *insertEnd* in the previous header file but it also works fine.

main.cpp

```
#include "arrayListType.h"

int main() {
    arrayListType<felinoTipo> listaFelinos(20);

    felinoTipo felinoTemp1("Tigre", "Tigrillo", 1.1, 1.1);

    listaFelinos.insertEnd(felinoTemp1);

    listaFelinos[0]; //Line X

    return 0;
}
```

The problem arises in line marked X. When I comment that line out and build the project, no errors are found. But when I include that line of code I get the error **invalid initialization of reference of type 'arrayListType&' from expression of type 'felinoTipo'  main.cpp**. My main intention is to store the reference obtained by the operator overloading function in an array of pointers of a base class of the felinoTipo to use virtual functions to print out the objects' attributes.

Any idea why this problem arises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operator returns this type:

```
arrayListType<elemType>&
```

but you want to return

```
elemType&
```

The compiler is complaining about the invalid conversion from one to the other.

You need something along these lines:

```
template <class elemType>
class arrayListType {
public:
    typedef elemType element_type;
    element_type& operator[](int);
    const element_type& operator[](int) const; // good idea to provide const overload
....
};
```

then

```
auto& e = listaFelinos[0];
```

or, if you don't have C++11,

```
arrayListType<felinoTipo>::element_type& e = listaFelinos[0];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the problem. Actually, I only had to change arrayListType<elemType>& for elemType& in the template header for the operator overloading function. Thanks again.